# I can not run an Android application with SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I tried to create a database (SQLite, SQLiteOpenHelper) on an Android project, but when I run my app at that time application says:

> "Sorry the application My application has stopped"

Why does this happen?

My class of the logical database:

```
public class DataBaseManager {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Clientes";

    public static final String CN_ID = "_nuip";
    public static final String CN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String CN_DATE = "Date";
    public static final String CN_CASH = "Cash";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = " create tabla" + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + CN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , "
            + CN_NAME + " text not null,"
            + CN_DATE + " text not null,"
            + CN_CASH + " text);";
}
```

My class extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME  = "clientes.sqlite" ;
    private static final int DB_SCHEME_VERSION = 1;

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
         super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_SCHEME_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DataBaseManager.CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper adm = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db2 = adm.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your logcat and code?

Comment: Have you tried to do Google.

Comment: @SarithaG Hi, Yes, already there, excuse me.

Comment: Whenever you see the **force close** exception, you should check the **logcat** window where you would see the exception log and it would help you to understand the cause of the issue!

Comment: use **table** instead of **tabla** in create table statement?

Comment: My logcat   ` 887-1487/? W/ActivityManager﹕ getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10093 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output `

Comment: See if this helps finding your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

First you delete the memory cache and data of your applications, in settings>Manager Applications>My App.
then, add this line in your query "IF NOT EXISTS" , so your query are;


`public static final String CREATE_TABLE = " create tabla" + TABLE_NAME + " IF NOT EXISTS ("
        + CN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , "
        + CN_NAME + " text not null,"
        + CN_DATE + " text not null,"
        + CN_CASH + " text);";`

Answer (score 0):

Correct you code with this code.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
    + TABLE_NAME + " ("
    + CN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + CN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + CN_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + CN_CASH + " TEXT);";
}
```